# Spring Java application starting twice on Jetty

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jetty

I have a server that is based on Spring MVC. When I run this application using the `mvn jetty: run` command, it runs normally. But when I run using the `mvn clean package` command and I send my `.war` to the Jetty container, this application is initialized twice.

I believe the problem is in the configuration of my Jetty, since at startup via `mvn jetty: run` it runs normally.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>...</artifactId>
  <version>...</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <mail.version>1.5.4</mail.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>

    <plugins>
      <!-- WAR -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Compile -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
          <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Properties -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                ..
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Flyway -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>flyway_medical_box_db</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>info</goal>
              <goal>repair</goal>
              <goal>migrate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <baselineOnMigrate>true</baselineOnMigrate>
              <driver>${jdbc.driver}</driver>
              <url>${jdbc.url}</url>
              <user>${jdbc.username}</user>
              <password>${jdbc.password}</password>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Jetty
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.12.v20150709</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
              <name>org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log</name>
              <value>org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog</value>
            </systemProperty>
            <systemProperty>
              <name>logback.configurationFile</name>
              <value>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/logback.xml</value>
            </systemProperty>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>-->

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>pagseguro</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <groupId>br.com.uol.pagseguro</groupId>
              <artifactId>pagseguro</artifactId>
              <version>2.5.2</version>
              <packaging>jar</packaging>
              <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/vendor/pagseguro/pagseguro-api-2.5.2.jar</file>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Security -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hashids</groupId>
      <artifactId>hashids</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20151123</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons Lang -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.slugify</groupId>
      <artifactId>slugify</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Mime Type -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
      <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- File Upload -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
          <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.11</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Connection Pool -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
      <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Repository -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Mail -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
      <version>${mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
      <version>${mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.19</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my jetty.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
    <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/myapp.war</Set>
    <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>
</Configure>
```

This is my start.ini:

```
#===========================================================
# Jetty Startup 
#
# Starting Jetty from this {jetty.home} is not recommended.
#
# A proper {jetty.base} directory should be configured, instead
# of making changes to this {jetty.home} directory.
#
# See documentation about {jetty.base} at
# http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html
#
# A demo-base directory has been provided as an example of
# this sort of setup.
#
# $ cd demo-base
# $ java -jar ../start.jar
#
#===========================================================

# To disable the warning message, comment the following line
--module=home-base-warning

# --------------------------------------- 
# Module: ext
--module=ext


# --------------------------------------- 
# Module: resources
--module=resources


# --------------------------------------- 
# Module: server
--module=server

### ThreadPool configuration
## Minimum number of threads
# jetty.threadPool.minThreads=10

## Maximum number of threads
# jetty.threadPool.maxThreads=200

## Thread idle timeout (in milliseconds)
# jetty.threadPool.idleTimeout=60000

### Common HTTP configuration
## Scheme to use to build URIs for secure redirects
# jetty.httpConfig.secureScheme=https

## Port to use to build URIs for secure redirects
# jetty.httpConfig.securePort=8443

## Response content buffer size (in bytes)
# jetty.httpConfig.outputBufferSize=32768

## Max response content write length that is buffered (in bytes)
# jetty.httpConfig.outputAggregationSize=8192

## Max request headers size (in bytes)
# jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize=8192

## Max response headers size (in bytes)
# jetty.httpConfig.responseHeaderSize=8192

## Whether to send the Server: header
# jetty.httpConfig.sendServerVersion=true

## Whether to send the Date: header
# jetty.httpConfig.sendDateHeader=false

## Max per-connection header cache size (in nodes)
# jetty.httpConfig.headerCacheSize=512

## Whether, for requests with content, delay dispatch until some content has arrived
# jetty.httpConfig.delayDispatchUntilContent=true

## Maximum number of error dispatches to prevent looping
# jetty.httpConfig.maxErrorDispatches=10

### Server configuration
## Whether ctrl+c on the console gracefully stops the Jetty server
# jetty.server.stopAtShutdown=true

## Dump the state of the Jetty server, components, and webapps after startup
# jetty.server.dumpAfterStart=false

## Dump the state of the Jetty server, components, and webapps before shutdown
# jetty.server.dumpBeforeStop=false

# --------------------------------------- 
# Module: http
--module=http

### HTTP Connector Configuration

## Connector host/address to bind to
# jetty.http.host=0.0.0.0

## Connector port to listen on
# jetty.http.port=8080

## Connector idle timeout in milliseconds
# jetty.http.idleTimeout=30000

## Connector socket linger time in seconds (-1 to disable)
# jetty.http.soLingerTime=-1

## Number of acceptors (-1 picks default based on number of cores)
# jetty.http.acceptors=-1

## Number of selectors (-1 picks default based on number of cores)
# jetty.http.selectors=-1

## ServerSocketChannel backlog (0 picks platform default)
# jetty.http.acceptorQueueSize=0

## Thread priority delta to give to acceptor threads
# jetty.http.acceptorPriorityDelta=0

# --------------------------------------- 
# Module: deploy
--module=deploy

# Monitored directory name (relative to $jetty.base)
# jetty.deploy.monitoredDir=webapps

# Monitored directory scan period (seconds)
# jetty.deploy.scanInterval=1

# Whether to extract *.war files
# jetty.deploy.extractWars=true

# --------------------------------------- 
# Module: jsp
--module=jsp


# --------------------------------------- 
# Module: websocket
--module=websocket


# --------------------------------------- 
# Module: jstl
--module=jstl


--module=ssl
--module=https
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  "Send my war to the jetty container" means what?  how are you doing that? how are you starting the jetty container? what does your `${jetty.base}` directory look like?  You pasted the `${jetty.home}/start.ini`, but that's not supposed to be used (even says so in that file header!)

Comment: How do you "send my .war to the Jetty container" - UPS or FedEx? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what my mistake was.

In my webapps folder I had the `.xml` with my start configuration and my `.war`. I just change folder of the `.war` file, I keep the `.xml` in the webapps folder and the application don't start twice.